# According to the Assembly of God, must a person love God to get into heaven, if he believes in Christ?

Tags: soteriology, heaven, forgiveness, pentecostalism, assurance-of-salvation

I was always taught, and my reading of the Bible (admittedly it has holes) tell me that the requirement to get into heaven is to accept Jesus as one's savior; that is, one must acknowledge one's status as a sinner, one must acknowledge Jesus is the Son of God, and one must accept the offer of grace and salvation through Jesus's shed blood.

I notice that in there, there is nothing about loving God, or even liking Him. Is there anything in the Bible that says we are actually required to love God to get into heaven? Or, like the begrudging taxpayer, can we avoid punishment from someone we're not endeared to simply by 'following the rules'?

I am looking for the Evangelical perspective on this, Assembly of God, if possible, with the scriptural basis for their view.

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for this site: you appear to be looking for the "true answer," but given the variety of views held by people who associate themselves with Christianity, we can't do that here.  Instead, we describe what specific groups of Christians believe, so if you'd like to ask for the view of a particular tradition, this question may be answerable.  When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Apologies. I was simply looking for a biblical basis pro/contra. Thanks.

Comment: Which would you prefer?  Pro or contra?  Both in the same question is too much, but you could ask pro in one question and contra in another if you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to hopefully be more in line with what is appropriate here. I will take a close look at the tour material.

Comment: Thanks for your edit!  I made one further modification, so that it's just asking for the Assembly of God's view.  The "biblical basis for" could be asked separately, and it would allow any biblical argument (not just those made by the AoG) to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several scripture reference for your reflection and possibly, revelation:

John 3:3 - Jesus answered him, “Truly, truly, I say to you, unless one is born again he cannot see the kingdom of God.”

John 3:16 - “For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life.

John 3:36 - Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life; whoever does not obey the Son shall not see life, but the wrath of God remains on him.

John 14:6 - Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.

Romans 10:9-10 - Because, if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved. For with the heart one believes and is justified, and with the mouth one confesses and is saved.

Ephesians 2:8-9 - For by grace you have been saved through faith. And this is not your own doing; it is the gift of God, not a result of works, so that no one may boast.

These scripture references shown above align with your known and accepted perspective above. Additionally, you will fine a couple of statements made by Jesus that must also be considered, in Matthew as follows:

Matthew 22:

37 Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’ 
38 This is the first and greatest commandment. 
39 And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’
40 All the Law and the Prophets hang on these two commandments.”

Matthew 5:

14 “You are the light of the world. A city set on a hill cannot be hidden. 
15 Nor do people light a lamp and put it under a basket, but on a stand, and it gives light to all in the house. 
16 In the same way, let your light shine before others, so that[b] they may see your good works and give glory to your Father who is in heaven.
17 “Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. 
18 For truly, I say to you, until heaven and earth pass away, not an iota, not a dot, will pass from the Law until all is accomplished. 
19 Therefore whoever relaxes one of the least of these commandments and teaches others to do the same will be called least in the kingdom of heaven, but whoever does them and teaches them will be called great in the kingdom of heaven. 
20 For I tell you, unless your righteousness exceeds that of the scribes and Pharisees, you will never enter the kingdom of heaven.

In Closing: 
Numbers 6:24-26
24 “The Lord bless you and keep you;
25 The Lord make His face shine upon you, And be gracious to you;
26 The Lord lift up His countenance upon you, And give you peace.”’

Peace

Comment: This is an excellent answer. The second-to-last two paragraphs clarify it greatly. Thank you very much!

Comment: OP accepted the answer, but this doesn't actually address his question: what does the Assemblies of God say about the question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your point of view. I took it for granted that AoG beliefs were known and accepted as truth, since there was a request for scripture and AoG was chosen as a part of the question. To add more clarity, the very first AoG belief is the following:

"WE BELIEVE...The Scriptures are Inspired by God and declare His design and plan for mankind."

These beliefs can be found [here](http://ag.org/top/beliefs/statement_of_fundamental_truths/sft_short.cfm). I submit AoG's perspective is clear based on scripture (some of which have been identified) that is inspired by God. Thanks and I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Yes. I specified AoG because I had to narrow the question, and I took the AoG's literal interpretation of the Scripture as a given. That's why I chose their perspective for my request.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is *Yes* beacuse in John 3:16 it says

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that
>   whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

So I think that you do have to love him to get into, heaven but God loves everyone no matter what happens.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.  This is a Q&A site.  Please take the [tour] to see how answers should be supportable rather than opinion based.  Since the question asked about the beliefes of Assembly of God, a discrete Christian denomination, answers should address this question from the perspective of that denomination of Christian belief.  Supporting doctrine, or other articles of belief from AoG are helpful in supporting an answer, beyond any scriptural citation (which you did provide.).  Thanks for participating and once again, welcome.